# New Features in C++ - what does this code mean

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was going through self learning of std::make_unique functionality where I found the below declaration at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

```
template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );
```

I am completely not able to understand the signature of the method / function above.

Comment: Your second question makes this too broad. Why are you trying to learn every new feature?

Comment: FYI though: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html

Comment: No - not all but at least what they are like how I learned C++ 98 similarly I wish to advance my skills to the new level by step by step practice by practice like the same way I learned C++ 98

Comment: Read about [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). But you should take several days to read some [good C++11 programming book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/841108). Asking questions for every new features of C++ is inappropriate here.

Comment: Read [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) article by Thomas Becker explaining move semantics and rvalue references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many "new" features used in this declaration:

- templates (`template` keyword; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B))
- variadic templates (the `...` argument; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)
- smart pointers (`unique_ptr`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)
- rvalue references (`Args&&`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors)

Basically the code means "declare a template for functions with an arbitrary number of parameters of any type and return a unique_ptr specialised for the given type T". In addition the rvalue reference (&&) tells you that the parameters will be moved instead of copied.

In short: `make_unique<Type>(v)` is basically the same as `unique_ptr<Type>(new Type(v))`.

Comment: The main value of C++14's ``std::make_unique<T>`` in addition to being both convenient and an equivalent to C++11's ``std::make_shared<T>`` is that exception handling semantics are clearer if the ``new`` throws vs. the ctor throws. The only downside is that Visual Studio IntelliSense isn't as helpful as it could be with the parameters.